# Change Rewrite rule depending on the URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a domain example.com which currently points to example123.com. I only want to hide the index.php file when I am at example.com, not example123.com. I'm on Apache 2.2 so I can't use the `<if>` statement.

How can I possibly do it?

I currently have:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^example.com.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```

But this doesn't work because this can take away the index.php from both domains. I only need to do that with one.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code in you htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [NC,L]
```